# What's the best practice for these kinds of routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Job` model that `belongs_to` three users (customer, employee, and qa). The customer is set to `current_user` when the job is created, but the employee and qa users pick their jobs from the pool of unclaimed jobs.

The way I have this implemented currently is as follows: `match 'jobs/:id/assign/:type/:user_id' => 'jobs#assign'` with an `assign` method with a case statement on `params[:type]`. So, for example, `jobs/1/assign/qa/1` assigns user 1 as the qa for job 1.

This works, but it seems sloppy and I'd like to replace it with something cleaner. Is there a common convention for situations like this?

**Edit:** Users can have both employee and qa roles simultaneously. That's what's making me feel forcing into such a complex route.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submitted_jobs,  :class_name => 'Job', :foreign_key => 'customer_id'
  has_many :assigned_jobs,   :class_name => 'Job', :foreign_key => 'employee_id'
  has_many :reviewed_jobs,   :class_name => 'Job', :foreign_key => 'qa_id'

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'customer_id'
  belongs_to :employee, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'employee_id'
  belongs_to :qa,       :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'qa_id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider a more RESTful approach to your problem. Two of the things [RESTful Best Practices](http://www.slideshare.net/calamitas/restful-best-practices) cites as "classic beginner's mistakes" is to "strongly mirror your ActiveRecord data model to choose your resources" and to "add custom methods if the standard ones don't fit."

> ***Nouns*** are the new verbs
>
> - Change your way of explaining the scenario, an action
>
>   - Use a **noun** to describe the action
>   - The noun given to your scenario *is* the resource you're looking for
> - A user **subscribes** to a group **->** A **subscription** is created
> - The project is **validated** by its owner **->** A **project validation** is created
> - The user **deactivates** his account **->** A **user account activation** is deleted

You could easily create a "Job Assignment" resource (*not* necessarily a separate model) and, for example, `create` one with the right parameters. In rough pseudo-Rails:

```
# routes
resources :job_assignments, :only => [:create, :delete] # or whatever you need

# job_assignments_controller
class JobAssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    job  = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    user.assign(job, params[:job_type]) # handle model logic
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    job  = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    user.unassign(job, params[:job_type]) # handle model logic
  end
end
```

There are some good examples in the presentation (starting on slide 32).

Comment: I had a feeling there was a better approach. This is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a great way about solving this is design your routes first which is what you're doing.

Your current routing is great if the "Job" and the assignee are well known in advance. In my opinion if you stuff the the job AND the assignee type information in the route you're doing too much.

Do the employees/qa also login and pick their own jobs? If they do, then their own information will be available on the server side in "current_user".

In that case, the route should ideally be "/job/:id/pick" going to "JobsController#pick" action with a POST request for example. In your controller action you would get the eemployee/qa user info in the current_user.

```
config/routes.rb

resource :jobs do
  member do
    post :pick
  end
end

in app/controller/jobs_controller.rb

def pick
  job = Job.find(params[:id])
  current_user.jobs << job # User has_many :jobs
  # or
  job.user = current_user
  ...
end
```

Please do let me know if employees/qa do NOT login and i'll update solution accordingly with another solution.

Comment: I agree that I'm stuffing too many parameters in the route, but the situation is slightly complicated by the fact that users can have both employee and qa roles at the same time. Because of this, I couldn't see a way around differentiating between the two assignments in the route itself.

Comment: No worries. So how does a user selects a job for assignment? Click on one of two buttons 'Pick as Employee', 'Pick as QA' for each unclaimed job? Choose something from a dropdown?

Comment: There will be a number of table views available to the users based on their roles. For example, a user that is only an employee will be able to see a table of jobs that have no employee assigned to them. A user with the qa role will be able to see another table with jobs that need to be reviewed. A user with both roles will have access to both tables. Jobs must be completed before they can be reviewed, so there will only be one button to pick the job, based on its context.