# Assigning an ID in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am working on a test app that has two models - Customers and Jobs.  A Customer has_many jobs and a Job belongs_to a Customer.

On the customer view page, there is a link_to create a New Job as follows:

```
<%= link_to "New Job", new_job_path %>
```

When the user clicks this New Job link on the customer page I want the job to be assigned to the corresponding customer id from the customer view page.

In searching for an answer I found this:  [What's the best practice for these kinds of routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025658/whats-the-best-practice-for-these-kinds-of-routes)

So I set up a separate controller to assign the customer id to the job as follows (job_assignments_controller.rb):

```
class JobAssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
    job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    customer.assign(job, params[:job_type])
  end

  def destroy
    customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
    job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    customer.unassign(job, params[:job_type])
  end
end
```

And I have set up my resource routes as follows:

```
  resources :job_assignments, :only => [:create]
```

I have created customer_id as a foreign key on the jobs table and can manually assign jobs to a customer id using the Rails Console.

I don't know how to proceed from here to accomplish my goal (have customer id auto assign to the job id when the new job link is clicked from the customer view page).

Any thoughts or ideas about if I am on the right track or about what I am missing?

Addendum:

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
 <% if @job.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
     <h2><%= pluralize(@job.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this job from being saved:</h2>

     <ul>
     <% @job.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <li><%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :installation %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :installation %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :install_date %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :install_date %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :delivery %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :delivery %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :box_count %><br>
   <%= f.number_field :box_count %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :room_type %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :room_type %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :material %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :material %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :exterior_colour %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :exterior_colour %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Addendum 2:

jobs_controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  def show
  end


  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end


  def edit
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)

    respond_to do |format|
    if @job.save
      format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @job }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
  if @job.update(job_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def destroy
  @job.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to jobs_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_job
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def job_params
   params.require(:job).permit(:job_number, :installation, :install_date, :delivery, :box_count, :room_type, :material, :exterior_colour)
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you want to have auto assigned value of `customer_id` to store in `jobs`?

Comment: Post your `jobs_controller` and `new.html.erb` or `_form.html.erb`

Comment: @RAJ added both.  And yes, I want the customer_id to auto assign and store in jobs.

Comment: you need to show us code of view page for adding new job (not customer)

Comment: @RAJ my mistake, the form has been changed accordingly above.

Comment: Thanks.. anyways, Have a look on my answer, I think that can solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `JobAssignmentsController` at-least for populating `customer_id` field.

You should add nested resource routes enclosing `jobs` by `cusmoters`. In routes.rb

```
resources :customers do
  resources :jobs
end
```

Modify link as (cross check path name by `rake routes` and `customer_id` is `id` of customer for which this link will create job):

```
<%= link_to "New Job", new_customer_job_path(customer_id) %>
```

In `new` action of `jobs_controller.rb` you should take benefit of associations. Build `job` object in relation with `customer`.

Add

```
customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
@job = customer.jobs.build
```

instead of

```
@job = Job.new
```

It will pre-populate your `customer_id`.

Read [**More**](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671632&seqNum=7)

Comment: I get an undefined local variable or method error for current_customer.  Keep in mind - Users log in and populate the app with customers and jobs.  So customers never log in.  I just want to have a link on the customer page to create a new job and pull that customers id into the job.

Comment: Getting very close - now when I click on the new job link I get an error that states:  Couldn't find Customer with id=customer_id.  So now it's looking for the id, but not pulling it down.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that you need to dynamically add  id of customer for which you wanted to create job in place of `customer_id` in `link_to`

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that - do you have any resources I can read?